# Why does an undefined error occur when assigning default values ​after destructuring and assigning props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having some issues with typescript in React.
Typescript, eslint, prettier, react, and webstorm have all been updated to the latest versions. As a result, errors that did not occur in the past occur. However, when run on the web, it works well without errors.

A typical problem is an error that occurs when assigning a default value to a variable with an optional type after destructuring and assigning it (although it works well).

#### package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.141",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.6",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "mobx": "^6.10.0",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^4.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.7",
    "swagger-ui-react": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.11",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@types/swagger-ui-react": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.33.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^14.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "prettier": "^3.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.4",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
```

#### code example

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Radio from '@components/Radio';

interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  handleClick: (value: string) => void;
  label: string;
  isChecked?: boolean;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}

const Layout = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Text = styled.label`
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-left: 6px;
`;

const RadioWithLabel = ({
  id,
  name,
  handleClick,
  label,
  isChecked = false,
  style,
}: Props) => (
  <Layout style={style}>
    <Radio
      id={id}
      name={name}
      handleClick={handleClick}
      isChecked={isChecked}
    />
    <Text htmlFor={id}>{label}</Text>
  </Layout>
);

export default RadioWithLabel;
```

#### errror

[image: eonju]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the isChecked value of your Radio component is a boolean, but your isChecked variable is an optionnal boolean

#### Solution 1

Change
`isChecked?: boolean`
to
`isChecked: boolean`

#### Solution 2

Since your problem appeared after you updated the typescript version in your project, this could be caused by a new default value for the "strictNullChecks" config

In your tsconfig.jsonfile, set `"strictNullChecks": false`

#### Solution 3

Provide a fallback value to your Radio "isChecked" property

```
isChecked={isChecked || false}
```

Comment: I know that by changing the optional type, the undefined error can of course be resolved. However, to avoid always passing unnecessary props, I used optional type. What I'm curious about is why an error that did not occur in the past occurred and whether the way to use the optional type was grammatically incorrect.

Comment: In this case, I'm pretty sure that it is grammatically incorrect because your Radio component has to be either checked or unchecked. One thing you could try is to go in your tsconfig.json and set “strictNullChecks” to false. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Comment: You saved my time!! According to your opinion, it would be better not to use optional for the radio button's checked prop. Also, I think I need to think about why strictNullCheck was changed. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the optional check in your interface declaration of `Props`

```
interface Props {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  handleClick: (value: string) => void;
  label: string;
  isChecked?: boolean;  // <-- HERE, remove the ? from '?:'
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
}
```

The Typescript thinks that `isCheck` could be either `boolean` or `undefined` regardless of whether you provided a fallback value in the function argument, when the `Radio` component expects the `isChecked` to always be `boolean`.

However, if you  don't like this solution, you can instead provide a fallback value for the `isCheck` prop

```
    <Radio
      {...otherProps}
      isChecked={isChecked || false}
    />
```

or even just

```
    <Radio
      {...otherProps}
      isChecked={!!isChecked}
    />
```

So the `isChecked` props for `Radio` will always get an `boolean` and making both Radio and Typescript happy :D